# put 3D world coordinates in 2D array

Tags: python, opencv, 3d

I'm working with 3D image processing using OpenCV and Python.

I can make from two points in two images (left and right)  a world coordinate (X, Y, Z).

For my remainder of the program:
It’s important to have a 2D array that corresponds to the left (or right) image pixels.

He needs to recognize objects in a normal 2D image. When that is done giving the x, y, z world coordinate of the founded object. This he does giving the (x, y) of the image en with this (x, y)  getting the x, y, z world coordinate.

My question is: Is there a special function for it or how can I do this?

Comment: I do not understand your question- there are two images, you need a function that will find an object in the first image (X, Y), and use that to find the Z coordinate from an image from a different angle?  What sort of images are these?

Comment: I am doing line detection in a building; I have a 3D camera so left image I find the line. Only for the application I need a 2D array so for the pixel position I find, I want to look in the 2D array for the x,y,z point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use  this function for calculation of the disparity:

```
disp = stereo.compute(imgL, imgR).astype(np.float32) / 16.0
```

When you want your array with the 3D points you need to use this function, the output is the same size as your image. On every pixel you see the x,y,z position:

```
points = cv2.reprojectImageTo3D(disp, Q)
```

If you chose a point and he gives a weird return or nothing, then there isn't a x,y,z position available for that point of course.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use glm you can try this:

```
glm::vec3 array[image_resolution_y][image_resolution_x];

array[0][0][0] = x;
array[0][0][1] = y;
array[0][0][2] = z;
```

In Linux you can install glm with apt-get install libglm-dev

But of your course you can just create a point struct / class and use this.

```
struct Point3D
{
float x;
float y;
float z;
};

Point3D array [image_resolution_y][image_resolution_x];
array[0][0].x = x;
array[0][0].y = y;
array[0][0].z = z;
```